# Kusto sub query selection using toscalar - returns only last matching record

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, kql

I am referring  [sqlcheatsheet - Nested queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet)

Query 1:

```
traces
    | where customDimensions.Domain == "someDomain"
    | where message contains "some-text" 
    | project itemId=substring(itemId,indexof(itemId,"-"),strlen(itemId))
```

Result :

itemId

> -c580-11e9-888a-8776d3f65945
> -c580-11e9-888a-8776d3f65945
> -c580-11e9-9b01-c3be0f4a2bf2

Query 2:

```
traces
    | where customDimensions.Domain == "someDomain"
    | where itemId has toscalar(
    traces
        | where customDimensions.Domain == "someDomain"
        | where message contains "some-text"  
        | project itemId=substring(itemId,indexof(itemId,"-"),strlen(itemId)))
```

Result for the second query returns records matching only last record of sub query

ie:) > -c580-11e9-9b01-c3be0f4a2bf2

Question :

How get entire result set that has matching with all the three items.

My requirement is to take entire sequence of logs for a particular request.

To get that I have below inputs, I could able to take one log, from that I can find ItemId

The itemId looks like `"b5066283-c7ea-11e9-9e9b-2ff40863cba4"`. Rest of all logs related to this request must have `"-c7ea-11e9-9e9b-2ff40863cba4"` this value. Only first part will get incremented like `b5066284` , `b5066285`, `b5066286` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toscalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/toscalarfunction), as its name implies, returns a scalar value.

Given a tabular argument with `N` columns and `M` rows it'll return the value in the 1st column and the 1st row.

*For example*: the following will return a single value - `1`

```kql
let T = datatable(a:int, b:int, c:int)
[
    1,2,3,
    4,5,6,
    7,8,9,
]
;
print toscalar(T)
```

If I understand the intention in your 2nd query correctly, you should be able to achieve your requirement by using [`has_any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/has-anyoperator).

*For example*:

```kql
let T = datatable(item_id:string)
[
    "c580-11e9-888a-8776d3f65945",
    "c580-11e9-888a-8776d3f65945",
    "c580-11e9-9b01-c3be0f4a2bf2",
]
;
T
| where item_id has_any (
    (
        T
        | parse item_id  with * "-" item_id
    )
)
```

Comment: My requirement is to take entire sequence of logs for a particular request.

To get that I have below inputs, I could able to take one log from that I can find ItemId

The itemId looks like "b5066283-c7ea-11e9-9e9b-2ff40863cba4". Rest of all logs related to this request must have "-c7ea-11e9-9e9b-2ff40863cba4" this value only first part will get incremented like b5066284 , b5066285, b5066286 like that.

Comment: @Yoni can you please explain what is "Scalar" value and why is it needed? What happens to a timestamp or string when toscalar() is applied.

Comment: This answer would be even better if the first sentence were expanded.  For instance, what precisely does it mean to return a scalar value?  The meaning of the answer seems to hinge on it, and someone might not know.

Comment: A tabular argument includes values in at least 1 column and at least 1 row. Each value  in a specific "cell" (given row and column) is a scalar value. You can fetch a scalar argument firm a tabular argument using `toscalar()` - this will return the value in the first column in the first row. The value itself is taken as-is, and isn't modified as a result of invoking `toscalar()`